# Setting KeystoneJS Date format

Tags: javascript, date, format, keystonejs

I can't seem to set the date format in my keystone JS blog and on other pages.

If I use {{ publishedDate }} in the template (I'm using handlebars) all is fine except that it gives me something like this: Thu Mar 23 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) which is obviously not fine.

```
{{ post.publishedDate.format('D MMMM') }}
{{ post._.publishedDate.format('D MMMM') }}
{{ publishedDate.format('D MMMM') }}
```

All return an error as follows:
Parse error on line 18:
... post.publishedDate.format('D MMMM') }}<
-----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'

I've also tried changing things in the model:

```
publishedDate: { type: Types.Date, index: true, format: 'YYYY', dependsOn: { state: 'published' }},
```

And numerous variations thereof. I've looked at the keystone documentation at: http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#fieldtypes-date and have tried to implement what it says there but it's still not working.

This should actually be really simple and I'm sure it is - I just don't know how to do it(!)

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underscore methods exist on the document, not on the property. The second line of code you have should work; [the `format` underscore function](http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#fieldtypes-date) will format the `publishedDate` item using your desired format (defaults to `Do MMM YYYY` if you don't provide an argument, but you can specify your own Moment.js formatting by providing an argument to `format`).

```
{{ post._.publishedDate.format('D MMMM') }}
```

As long as `post` is provided as a local variable to your Handlebars template (`locals.post = post` in your route), that should not return any errors.

**EDIT** 3/28/17

In Handlebars, you have to pass data to functions in a different way than Keystone documentation describes. They use Pug, so what you're trying to do would work in Pug. Handlebars evaluates functions differently. Try `{{post._.publishedDate.format "D MMMM"}}` The `"D MMMM"` string is passed to format and it works just fine then.

Comment: Thanks Shea... At girlfriends house atm and away from the pc. Getting back to it on Tuesday and will try to implement this. Cheers again.

Comment: Hmmm... have tried this and hasn't made any difference unfortunately. Just to give you a bit more context, in the route I have:                             
 var locals = res.locals;

 // Set locals
 locals.section = 'blog';
 locals.filters = {
  post: req.params.post,
 };
 
 locals.data = {
  posts: [],
 };

 locals.post = post;                                                                                               
and in the template I have: {{ post._.publishedDate.format('D MMMM') }}

It's still giving me the same error - anything really obvious I'm missing?

Comment: It might have to do with the spaces in your Handlebars template. Try `{{post._.publishedDate.format('D MMMM')}}`

Comment: No - tried that already - something more fundamental I think... I double checked package.json and underscore is in there - is there anything else that's essential to it? Moment or something like that?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out! In Handlebars, you have to pass data to functions in a different way than Keystone documentation describes. Try `{{post._.publishedDate.format "D MMMM"}}` The `"D MMMM"` string is passed to `format` and it works just fine then.

Comment: Ahhhh... now we're getting there :-) Did as you said and am now getting a different error (I think this constitutes progress!) :-) It's now saying: Missing helper: "publishedDate.format" ... I've read about these somewhere (yes, I'm very new to keystone!)... getting there though... is this just a case of playing around with index.js in the helpers folder?

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary; if `post` is the direct result of a mongoose query, it should have the underscore helper. `{{post._.publishedDate.format "D MMMM"}}` and `{{{post._.publishedDate.format "D MMMM"}}}` don't work? Come to [this Stack Overflow chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139249/discussion-on-keystonejs-and-handlebars-template) which makes it easier to communicate live.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Shea - help above and beyond the call of duty. Much appreciated ;-) Eventual solution (for anyone else interested) was - if running in a loop -  to create a virtual in the model as follows:

```
Post.schema.virtual('formattedDate').get(function () { 
    return this._.publishedDate.format("D MMMM"); 
});
```

and then, in the handlebars template use the following format:

```
{{formattedDate}}
```

If not running in a loop can be done simply with:

{{_.publishedDate.format "D MMMM"}}